# Reading Large Files in Java getting really slow

Tags: java, performance, io

I am trying to read a large file ~200 MB (~300 million lines of text). I am using a relatively standard way of reading like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numProcs; i++) {
    System.out.println("Parsing " + traceFilePrefix + i + ".prg");
    System.out.println("##########################");

    try {
        String line;
        int instrType;
        String hexAddr;
        ArrayList<Trace> traces = new ArrayList<Trace>();

        int lineNum = 1;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(traceFilePrefix + numProcs + "/" + traceFilePrefix + i + ".PRG"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.toUpperCase();
            // validate line format
            if (line.matches(regexLineFormat)) {
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
                instrType = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                hexAddr = tokenizer.nextToken();

                traces.add(new Trace(instrType, hexAddr));
            } else {
                // line is in invalid format
                System.err.println("ERR: line " + lineNum + " is invalid \"" + line + "\"");
            }
            lineNum++;

            if (lineNum % 1000 == 0) System.out.println("line " + lineNum); 
        }
        br.close();
        processorsTraces.add(i-1, traces);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I find that reading slows down at about line 20 million... in face it doesnt seem to progress at all ... how can I improve this? Whats the problem in this simple piece of code?

A latest run seem to run out of heap space ... I guess I cant store data in an arraylist like that?

This is supposed to be a simulator. It first parses trace files containing hexadecimal addresses of memory accesses. Then is supposed to run simulation of these data. This code snipplet only parses and stores the traces in an arraylist.

Comment: Comment the `traces.add` and see if you title is correct. I feel that reading is not a problem at all. It should be a memory, an issue of storing the millions of small objects. Actually, the average size of your lines is 300/200 = 1.5 bytes per item. The overhead will be huge. Since java performance is based on JIT, it does not care about memory efficiency and you will have about 100 bytes overhead per evert 1.5 bytes of real data. You'll need about 30 GB to store all your 300 mln items. Java is not suitable for this task and you have a wrong title.

Comment: To be pedantic… a 200 MB file cannot possibly contain 300 million lines of text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is almost certainly in the structure of your `Trace` class, and it's memory efficiency. You should ensure that the `instrType` and `hexAddress` are stored as memory efficient structures. The instrType appears to be an `int`, which is good, but just make sure that it is declared as an `int` in the Trace class.

The more likely problem is the size of the hexAddress String. You may not realise it but Strings are notorious for 'leaking' memory. In this case, you have a `line` and you think you are just getting the hexString from it... but in reality, the hexString contains the entire line.... yeah, really. For example, look at the following code:

```
public class SToken {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("99 bottles of beer");
        int instrType = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        String hexAddr = tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(instrType + hexAddr);
    }
}
```

Now, set a break-point in (I use eclipse) your IDE, and then run it, and you will see that hexAddr contains a char[] array for the entire line, and it has an offset of 3 and a count of 7.

Because of the way that String substring and other constructs work, they can consume huge amounts of memory for short strings... (in theory that memory is shared with other strings though). As a consequence, you are essentially storing the entire file in memory!!!!

At a minimum, you should change your code to:

```
hexAddr = new String(tokenizer.nextToken().toCharArray());
```

But even better would be:

```
long hexAddr = parseHexAddress(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

---

EDIT: Request to get help on how to debug the code:

To debug the code, you need to set a break-point in the method. Select the line `System.out.println(...);` and use the key-board short-cut Ctrl-Shift-B which will toggle a break-point, and you will get the 'dot' marker like the picture below:

[image]

Then, with that break-point enabled, you need to debug the program:

Right-click on the 'main' word in the `public static void main (String[] ...)` and select 'Debug As -> Java Application'

This should prompt you to go to the 'Debug' perspective, and you will have a window with the 'Variables' displayed. One of the variables will be `hexAddr` and you can expand it to show its contents. Here's a screen-shot:

[image]

From the variables section there are a few things of note. At the bottom, the 'value' variable is highlighted, and it's internal value is shown in the area below ( `[9, 9,  , b, o, ......, r]`

You can see the `count` and `offset` variables for `hexAddr` too. This means that the `hexAddr` variable stores the char[] array for the entire line, but also stores an offset and count in that array which it uses for managing the subset of the chars that this String instance is interested in

Comment: Ok I will change hex address to int first. Its currently a string

Comment: When I execute your code, I just get "99bottles" how do you get the array and stuff? I am using Eclipse J2EE Kepler.

Comment: "String theory" is true .... believe it or not. Haters will hate... :)

Comment: Note that the `char[]` sharing is no longer true in recent Oracle/OpenJDK releases (at least in Java 7 and I think even in newer Java 6 releases), it has been modified so that every `String` has its own `char[]`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - huh, did not know that. Thanks. I use IBM's JDK and it's still true there. I presume also true in the OP's environment.

Comment: I checked, and I'm not sure you're right. The copy-the-value constructor here, which is used in substring, etc. See: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cchar[]%29

Comment: @rolfl: I mis-remembered the exact versions: it's JDK8 since b40 and JDK7 since u6: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for the update. This is interesting and it is this type of information that will make a positive difference in my work later (when I discover one of those places where I took advantage of the sharing...)

Answer (score 6):

I see several issues that could impact performance

```
    if (line.matches(regexLineFormat)) {
```

If the file is large, compiling the regular expression would be a performance bottleneck.
Suggest to put the following block in to a static block:

```
 Pattern regexLineFormatPattern = Pattern.compile(regexLineFormat);
```

And then use

```
if (regexLineFormatPattern.matcher(line).matches()){
```

References: [Java Doc of Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

And then since you are already using regular expression, you could try to use regular expression to complete the work done by `StringTokenizer` to replace the following code:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
instrType = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
hexAddr = tokenizer.nextToken();
```

The `Matcher#group` method would be helpful to extract the value from the String.

The code would be like this:

```
//outside the looop, better in a static block
String regexLineFormat = "(\d+) ([^ ]+) ...."//define the capture groups here.

Pattern regexLineFormatPattern = Pattern.compile(regexLineFormat);

//in the method, inside the loop

Matcher matcher = regexLineFormatPattern.matches(line);

if( matcher.matches()){
   traces.add(new Trace(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)),matcher.group(2)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First:  When memory is an issue, you cannot read the entire data set into memory.  You need to follow an algorithm similar to (pseudo code)

```
while(notDone){
   readFixedAmountOfData();
   processData();
}
```

Right now, you are doing

```
readALLData(); // <- everything goes into memory
processData();
```

For specific points in your code:

- If you know the data is ASCII text, don't use Reader classes and don't use Strings, use raw InputStream (or some derivative) and use byte[].
- avoid superfluous calls that create excess objects (e.g. `line = line.toUpperCase()` creates a new String -- do you really need it in upper case?)
- What does the `Trace` class look like?  That will play a significant part of this.

Answer (score 2):

I would split this up into a 2-threaded program.

The first thread simply reads into a chunk of the file, say 100.000 (or 1 000.000) first lines, and stores it in an array.

Then the second thread would parse the lines and evaluate them according to your rules.

The first thread would then continue reading the next 100.000 lines, and the second thread does it magic on those lines, and so on until there are no more lines in the file.

What else? Well, you dont actually need your *lineNum* variable, because *i* will always have the same value.

Comment: The lecturer advised against using a threaded program because of complexities it introduces. I agree, this is supposed to be a small relatively easy assignment ...

Comment: I +1 because your answer corresponds to the (mis)title.

Answer (score 2):

If the file I/O is really what is slowing you down. Then you should consider how much memory you can afford to use at a given time, and find the trade of between the two.

Decide how much memory you can spare, then read in as much of the file as possible. Then parse out the lines once it is all loaded.

Reading in larger chunks will increase your file I/O speed.

Comment: I was commenting on the file read, as that can help speed it up. Space issues need to be address as a separate thing, which I was not addressing.

Comment: That is why I am telling that you ignored the question. Author clearly says that his problem is dramatically slowed down due to memory limit, which you do not address. Just saying that you have ignored the question does not mean that you responded the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 300/200 bytes per line, this means that you'll have a lot of identical items in your list. Consider [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to save your memory requirements. As experiment, add the same item 300 mln times in your list. It is the minumum amount of memory you need. See if you have so much.

I wonder how do you manage to have a type/address with 1.5 bytes/instruction. Since hex address is supposed to be different every time, you cannot use flyweight. Yet, you may use the heap as a cache whereas the program is stored on disk. Yet, [java is bad for disk swapping](http://valjok.blogspot.com/2013/04/java-gc-makes-memory-management.html) again.

Since you'll have a memory map, it may be cheaper to allocate an array `int[max_hex_address]` for storing the types. A 300 million of integers is only 1.2 GB.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you should change in the code is avoid reading binary file using [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html). It is meant for reading streams of character. You can use [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Close `io` streams in `finally` block so that they are closed even if an exception is thrown.

Also try increasing the buffer size of the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Oh i put `close()` in try since it also throws an exception. And in this simple program I thought of avoiding the need for so much try catch. Ok but I'll follow ur advice and try changing things

Comment: But I am actually reading characters? Its a text file?

Comment: I saw you have extension PRG

Comment: for some reason its a "PRG" file ... but the data inside is just text